# Accessing API layer

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to access an api function, for example I want to access the login function, I get the following error:

> "message": "An internal error occurred during your request!",

Looking in the log file, the following log is there:

> ERROR 2017-10-09 17:01:37,296 [11   ]
>   nHandling.AbpApiExceptionFilterAttribute - Processing of the HTTP
>   request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response
>   returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details.
>   System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException: Processing of the HTTP request
>   resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the
>   'Response' property of this exception for details.

I am using Postman to test. My URL is https://localhost:44347/api/Account/Authenticate. My header has Context-Type as `"application/json"` and in my Body I have the loginModel formatted as

```
{
"tenancyName": "tenantname",
"userNameOrEmailAddress": "admin",
"password": "123qwe"
}
```

Am not sure how else to proceed on this. Any ideas please? I have swagger installed as well.

I am using MVC + AngularJS template. I have not changed anything, just the default project.

Appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested with Fiddler and it works correctly.

[image: Fiddler test result]

Note: make sure you type **Content-Type** correctly, on the question you typed **Context-Type**

Comment: I was using postman to test my API and for some reason it doesn't work in postman but it works fine in fiddler. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Make a **POST** request! You may be missing this.